# How to add an argument to gradle command line and use it in build.gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

What I want to do:

build.gradle

```
...
splits {
    abi {
        enable project.property('splitApk')
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
...
```

How to pass the property 'splitApk' in Android Studio?
I've used **Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Command-line Options** and set it to:

```
-PsplitApk=true
```

but doesn't work.

Using the literal works fine, but I want to switch it in cmd-line:

```
...
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
...
```

Is there a way to enable or disable the `splits` configuration from Command-line props into build.gradle using Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-P` to set predefined properties. In your case that would be:

```
ext {
    splitApk = !project.hasProperty('splitApk')
}
```

At the top of your build.gradle, and then you can use the variable `splitApk`.

I see that you are adding a value in the command line options, what you want to do is just simply pass `-PsplitApk` there. You can then use it as a flag, if it is present `hasProperty` will return true, otherwise false.

Comment: Still not work... works only with explicit `enable true` declaration.
`INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113`

Comment: The example I gave you has the check inverted, did you account for that? You can see if the value changes by just printing it in the gradle script with `println(splitApk)` and then cehcking gradle console.

Comment: More one thing:
Is working, but `!project.hasProperty('splitApk')` is returning always TRUE...
How to configure it in Android Settings cmd-line?
`-P` seems not work

Comment: So, you either pass it in the compiler options and that value should return `true`, or you should remove it from the compiler options and it should return `false`. Make sure it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqYMH.png

Comment: Yes I've saw that the value is loading using `project.logger.lifecycle("splitApk: ${splitApk}")`, but the `enable splitApk` doesn't set the value of enable to true.